# Check if input field is null or empty in Lumen

Tags: php, forms, lumen

I'm currently using below method to check if an input field is null or empty in Lumen 5.5

```
if($request->has('gameId') && $request->input('gameId')!="") {
   $game_id = $request->input('gameId');
}
```

Is this the best way to check this? Are there any validate methods in Lumen?

Comment: `if(!empty($request->input('gameId'))) {
   $game_id = $request->input('gameId');
}`

Comment: I use`app('request')->input('gameId')` checks isset(), blank value.